# Downcasting from Object to Integer Runtime Error: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, downcast

Run time exception-- `java.lang.ClassCastingException`...

```
Integer intArr[] = new Integer[arrList.size()];
ArrayList <Integer> arrList =new ArrayList();
intArr=(Integer[])arrList.toArray(); // returns Object class which is downcaste to Integer;
```

I understand down-casting is not safe but why is this happening?
I also tried to converting `ArrayList` to `String` to `Integer` to `int`, but I get the same error.

Comment: can ArrayList contents be converted directly into int

Comment: No, as int is a primitive type and `ArrayList<int>` cannot be done. In other words, Generics cannot be applied on primitive types.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman thanks, just was wanted 1 line solution for converting ArrayList into primitive types...

Comment: You will have to write a wrapper that does convert `Integer[]` to `int[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this doesn't bind the ArrayList to type `Integer`.

```
ArrayList <Integer> arrList =new ArrayList();
```

Instead, this is what happens, `arrList` is assigned to an `ArrayList` of raw type, but that isn't a problem.

The problem lies in,

```
intArr=(Integer[])arrList.toArray();
```

since `arrList` is a raw-type (due to the assignment, it gets assigned as `new ArrayList<Object>()` by the compiler), you're effectively getting an `Object[]` instead.

Try assigning `arrList` to `new ArrayList<Integer>()` and do this:

```
intArr = arrList.toArray(new Integer[arrList.size()]);
```

Comment: thanks man, ur solutions always enlight my understanding of language beyond my questions(jimmy's Question, I know), thanks.....

Comment: arrList to new ArrayList<Integer>() doesn't work, used the last option..... same error java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: I just wrote this and it works for me: `List<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); Integer[] ints = arrList.toArray(new Integer[arrList.size()]);`.

Comment: 1st option just removes note of unchecked operations @compile time, 2nd option does the work, Why??

Comment: Because of the method `List<T>.toArray(T[] array);`. Because I've said that `arrList` is type `Integer`, the `toArray` method expects and `Integer` array (at compile-time). The implementation returns all internal values of the list to an array. In other words, the Generic type `T` is bounded to an Object `Integer`. Study Generics.

Comment: yes it works for me too... but have to do both, 1st and 2nd, ur 1st and my old constructor doesn't work it gives the error @runtime, but removes note of unchecked operations...

Comment: forcing arrList to be Integer type and using   intArr=(Integer[])arrList.toArray(); gives runtime error... but now things are sort out,thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try to do this

```
intArr = arrList.toArray(new Integer[arrList.size()]);
```

What you get is a typed `Integer` Array and not a Object array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to convert an array of objects to an array of integers.  Array is an object in itself and `Integer[]` is not a sub-class of `ArrayList`, nor vice versa.  What you have to do in your case is cast individual items, something like this:

```
Integer intArr[] = new Integer[arrList.size()];
for(int i=0; i<intArr.length; i++)
{
    intArr[i] = (Integer)arrList.get(i);
}
```

Naturally, you may get ClassCastException if individual elements in the array list are not of type Integer.

Comment: thanks, individual items a general solution of problems, any class conversion, but for here i found a constructor as specified by powerMicha,MaciejK or The Elite Gentleman... thanks

Answer (score 1):

`toArray(T[] a)` takes a paramter:
"a - the array into which the elements of the list are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runt"